# React working with dynamically generated nodes

Tags: reactjs

I just started with React and I'm trying to make a list where the user can enter a record number and the fields get auto populated, with the ability to add / delete rows and update them then save.

So far I got it to search successfully and update the two empty rows I manually inserted (I don't know how to get the add button to work yet), but I need to add that functionality, as well as the ability to delete a row while keeping everything else including any values the user updated on the other lines.

I've been playing with setState and I've tried doing in in the parent but I can't get it to work properly, here is my code so far:

```
      var empty_item = {
        "id": "",
        "order_id": "",
        "status": "",
        "currency": "",
        "authorized_service_cents": "",
        "authorized_mileage_cents": "",
        "zen_id": "",
        "parent_zen_id": "",
        "ffs": "",
        "wotypetext": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "phone_number": "",
        "secondary_phone_number": "",
        "z_cx_id": "",
        "email": ""
      }

      var WorkOrderTableRow = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
          return {
            item: empty_item,
            notice: '',
            notice_class: 'hide_notice'
          };
        },
        getWO: function(event){
          console.log("In Get WO");
          if(event.target.value && event.target.value.length >= 7){
            console.log(event.target.value);
            var url = "/api/wo/" + event.target.value;
            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: false,
              success: function(result) {
                if(result.rows && result.rows.length > 0){
                  this.setState({item: result.rows[0], notice: '', notice_class: 'hide_notice'});
                }else{
                  this.setState({item: empty_item, notice: result.message, notice_class: 'show_notice red-bg'});
                }
                console.log(result);
              }.bind(this),
              error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(url, status, err.toString());
              }.bind(this)
            });
          }else{
            this.setState({item: empty_item, notice: '', notice_class: 'hide'});
          }
        },
        handleWOChange: function(event){
          this.getWO(event);
          // this.state.data()
        },
        render: function(){
          return(
            <tr className="workOrderTableRow formRow wrapper">
              <td className="w_192">
                <input type="text" ref="wo" onChange={this.handleWOChange}/>
                <span className="tooltip">
                    <span className={this.state.notice_class}>{this.state.notice}</span>
                </span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div className="w_70">{this.state.item.parent_zen_id}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div className="w_192">{this.state.item.first_name} {this.state.item.last_name}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div className="w_192">{this.state.item.wotypetext}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div className="w_70">{this.state.item.authorized_service_cents / 100}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div className="w_70">{this.state.item.authorized_mileage_cents /100}</div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" className="w_70" placeholder="" value={this.state.item.amount_cents}/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <TaxCodeList tax_code_id={this.state.item.tax_code_id}/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <ExpenseTypeList expense_type={this.state.item.expense_type} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" className="pointer" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="button" className="btn-small row-extra remove-row red-bg pointer" value="X" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        }
      });

      //This is a component
      var MainWrapper = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
          return(
            <div className="mainWrapper wrapper">
              This is the main wrapper
              <InvoiceWrapper />
              <ResultWrapper />
            </div>
          );
        }
      });

      var ResultWrapper = React.createClass({

        render: function(){
          var getWO = this.getWO;

          return(
            <div className="resultWrapper wrapper">
              <div className="resultListWrapper wrapper">
                Results show here
              </div>
              <div className="entriesWrapper wrapper">
                <form>
                  <table className="work_order_table" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr className="formRow wrapper table_header">
                        <td className="w_192">Work Order #</td>
                        <td className="w_70">Case</td>
                        <td className="w_192">Customer</td>
                        <td className="w_192">Service</td>
                        <td className="w_70">Auth Amt.</td>
                        <td className="w_70">Auth Mil.</td>
                        <td className="w_70">Amount</td>
                        <td className="w_70">Tax Code</td>
                        <td className="w_192">Expense Type</td>
                        <td className="w_70"></td>
                        <td className="w_70"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <WorkOrderTableRow />
                      <WorkOrderTableRow />
                      <tr className="saveRow wrapper">
                        <td colSpan="10" className="left-text">
                          <input type="button" id="post" name="post" className="post btn pointer green-bg" value="POST" />
                          <input type="button" id="save_post" name="save_post" className="save_post btn mar-lft-5 pointer orange-bg" value="SAVE & POST" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="button" className="btn-small row-extra add-row green-bg pointer" value="+" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(
        <MainWrapper />,
        document.getElementById('content')
      );
```

Also, when I was experimenting with doing everything in the parent I kept losing focus in the textbox being typed in after the refresh, if we can avoid that it would be great.

Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the jsfiddle or codepen link with the code and narrow down the problem statement

Comment: Ok so this uses an internal API so I have no clue how to make it work, and I don't know enough about react to use a file instead, but here is the link anyways. https://jsfiddle.net/murtorius/hr9cfjrc/2/

Comment: Have you looked at the todomvc example?

Comment: I did but its a bit complicated for my limited knowledge unfortunately, is tehre a tutorial that walks you through creating it?